# Can I swap EC2 IPs by PHP or any other script

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-api-tools

I have two EC2 instances for Ethernet interface. If one instance fail other should come up.
Can I swap EC2 IPs by using any script. Please give any idea.

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried (show your code)? Also, have you considered using the Auto-Scaling feature of AWS to manage this process instead of hand-crafting a solution?

Comment: I was going though aws PHP API and it looking to not supporting this functionality. I have installed auto scaling tools. Do you have some idea how I can create or find that script.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of this site - the idea is, you do the research and come up with something, then post here if you get stuck.